# Camera View Limited Range

Tags: camera

I have attached a video screenshot of the issue. I can't seem to get my camera to display objects in the distance. Some Focal setting adjustments are required I guess but I'm new to all this. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.
Video link:  https://www.mediafire.com/file/umpnb3mqnwe0jus/Camera_Issue.mp4/file

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the "Clip End" of your camera to include everything you want to see in the view.

[image: Camera properties]